# Pytesseract doesn't recognize numbers properly

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I have this function to get the numbers from a sudoku table:

```
def extract_sudoku(image_path):
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
    thresholded = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blurred, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 11, 2)

    contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresholded.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    sudoku_contour = None
    for contour in contours:
        area = cv2.contourArea(contour)
        if area > 5000:
            epsilon = 0.02 * cv2.arcLength(contour, True)
            approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(contour, epsilon, True)
            if len(approx) == 4:
                sudoku_contour = approx
                break

    if sudoku_contour is None:
        print("Sudoku grid not found.")
        return

    dest_corners = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 450], [450, 450], [450, 0]], dtype=np.float32)
    transform_matrix = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(sudoku_contour.astype(np.float32), dest_corners)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, transform_matrix, (450, 450))

    grid = np.zeros((9, 9), dtype=np.uint8)
    cell_size = warped.shape[0] // 9
    for i in range(9):
        for j in range(9):
            cell = warped[i * cell_size:(i + 1) * cell_size, j * cell_size:(j + 1) * cell_size]
            digit = pytesseract.image_to_string(cell, config=config)
            if digit:
                grid[i, j] = int(digit)

    return grid
```

I have tried it with these images (a bunch from these pages, but this should show the puzzles well enough): [Sudoku 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T5CT3.png) [Sudoku 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwVqB.png)

This is the output I got for the latter:

```
[[0 0 0 6 0 0 9 1 0]
 [8 6 9 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 1 0 0 0 9 4 6 0]
 [0 7 6 0 0 0 8 0 0]
 [0 9 0 0 6 0 0 4 0]
 [0 0 7 9 1 0 3 0 0]
 [0 7 5 8 0 0 0 2 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0 0 9 7 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0 6 0 8 0]]
```

It seems to have the biggest problem with the 7s for the other page.

Anyone knows how to fix this? My Googling didn't really help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: try different psm configurations

Comment: you can pass in the `config` a digit-only option, maybe it help

Answer (score 0):

In my own experience with this kind of stuff, I find PyTesseract to be somewhat unreliable. Another model I found, which is both quick and accurate, is [PaddleOCR](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/). You can make OCR calls easily by first defining a reader, then reading a cv2 Image:

```py
from paddleocr import PaddleOCR
OCR = PaddleOCR(use_angle_cls=True, lang='en', show_log=False, rotation=False)
print(OCR.ocr(image))
```

See the [quickstart](https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/blob/release/2.7/doc/doc_en/quickstart_en.md) here for Python installation. Note: the `paddlepaddle` dependency is difficult to install if your Python version is 3.11 or above.